# Getting a foreign key field other than id in symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I have a table 'comment', investigation that has a field referencing another table 'sf_guard_user'.  At the moment when I put

```
<?php echo $investigationComment->getUserId() ?>
```

I get the id value of the foreign table row.  I want to be able to get the name field value.

Somewhere else in my project I was able to omit id from getUserId() and then put->getName() and it brought me that field value, but for this it's not doing it for some reason.  How can I get the name value for the foreign key row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get the relation object first and then call for any property of that relation.

```
<?php echo $comment->getUser()->getName() ?>
```

This will work if you defined an alias 'User' in your relation like this:

```
//config.yml
Comment:
  relations:
    sfGuardUser:
      alias: User
      foreignAlias: Comments
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
```

or

```
//config.yml
Comment:
  relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      foreignAlias: Comments
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
```

Comment: This is the bit form my yaml file.  I don't know what any of the words mean though!  Like whats the word immediately after relations refer to, is it the field name in the table?  Same with class, local, foreign and foereignAlias.  I
  `code`relations:
    user_id:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: comments`code`

Comment: Sorry if that doesn't make sense above, it's hard to put code in, it removes line space :(.

Comment: The word after 'relations' is either classname or alias. If it is classname, then you should to define an 'alias' property, otherwise - 'class' property. Just do whatever looks best for you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to add the following your foreign entity class

```
public function __toString(){
    return $this->getAPropertyOnYourEntity();
}
```

Now rather than returning the ID the entity can return any property you want from the __toString() function.